# por qué al querer pintar el texto ingresado en un textarea, me aparece esto: [object HTMLParagraphElement]

Tags: javascript

```
function drawComments() {
  var divNewComment = document.createElement("div");
  var newComment = document.createElement("p");

  divNewComment.appendChild(newComment);
  var containerComments = document.getElementById("container-comments");
  containerComments.appendChild(divNewComment);

  //crear elemento de texto usando la variable que guarda los datos que el usuario ingresa en el textarea
    var commentNewUsser = document.createTextNode(commentUser)
    comments.unshift(commentNewUsser);
    console.log(comments);
    console.log(commentNewUsser);
    newComment.appendChild(commentNewUsser);
}
```

Comment: Por favor podrías ser más explicita en lo que pides? No entiendo que tiene que ver el código con el título de la pregunta y así me es dificil colaborar